# Is it okay to upgrade from bionic packages?

Tags: 16.04

I had to add bionic https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ to install openssl_1.1.0g from a .deb it was providing.

Now if I run `apt update` it reports that I need to upgrade 500+ packages total of 600MB on 16.04?

If I run upgrade will I break anything, I'm running a website on it.

Comment: It will probably break a lot of things to graft beta software sources onto a support release.

Comment: Why did you add the bionic repo, and why do you need the specific openssl from bionic? Security fixes are already backported to the openssl package version in 16.04.

Comment: https://community.ubuntu.com/t/bionic-daily-is-out/1530/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `apt upgrade`, you will upgrade your system to Bionic. Whether it will "break anything" depends on various factors, but anyway it's probably not what you want.

Comment: Does anyone truly know when Bionic is still in beta The people testing bionic are not done finding all the bugs yet.question and even if it does not break right after the update lots.e New package versioons can come into bionic without as much testing as a stable release update and that have regressions. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QATeam/PerformingSRUVerification is not done on development releases. So if you ran `apt update` and `apt upgrade` no one could tell you what happens in the future until it is released. Why would you want this for your website.

Comment: @ianorlin https://community.ubuntu.com/t/bionic-daily-is-out/1530/2